# MySQL WHERE - wildcard to "ignore" option?

Tags: php, mysql, wildcard

Because of a legacy design issue, I am trying to figure the most efficient way to approach this problem.  Using a TABLE with two fields:
`pk int(10), year timestamp`  Where "pk" is the primary key, but also used in the document number being looked up.

The data I receive from the user may come in either as that integer, or a combination of items preceding the integer.  For example:

The document number the user comes from:  `"FM" + Last two digits of the year + "-A" + pk.`
So an example form from 2015, with a primary key of 1025 would be **FM15-A1025**.

Using AJAX, the user may search for any of the following to look up this (and other) forms:

```
F
FM
FM1
FM15
FM15-
FM15-A
FM15-A1
FM15-A10
FM15-A102
FM15-A1025
```

My question is, how, with a combination of MySQL and PHP, can I return all of the PK values that apply to this search?  Obviously, "F" and "FM" will return all values, but the year component will 2015 will give a different answer than 2020.

I am not aware of a MySQL wildcard character or method that allows you to ignore parts of the column in a search, and there is a lot of PHP (using a lot of CPU/memory in the process) for this simple look-up.  Currently, my PHP gets the job done, but it is incredibly complex for such a simple task:

```
$cleansearch = strtoupper(filter_var($_POST['search']['value'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));

$searchid = $searchyear ="";
if ($cleansearch==="p" || $cleansearch==="pk"){
   $searchid = " pk LIKE '%' ";
} else if (strlen($cleansearch) === 3) {
   for($i = 0; $i<10;  $i++   ) {
        $test = "IR".$i;
        if($test===$cleansearch){
            $searchid= "pk LIKE '%' ";
            $searchyear= " AND LEFT(DATE_FORMAT(year,'%y'), 1) =$i ";
        }       
    }
} elseif ((strlen($cleansearch) === 4) || (
    ((strlen($cleansearch)=== 5 && "-"===substr($cleansearch,4,1)) ||
    (strlen($cleansearch)=== 6 && "-D"===substr($cleansearch,4,2))))){
    $cleansearch=substr($cleansearch,0,4);
    for($i = 10; $i<100;  $i++   ) {
        $test = "IR".$i;
        if($test===$cleansearch){
            $searchid= "pk LIKE '%' ";
            $searchyear= " AND DATE_FORMAT(year,'%y') =$i ";
        }
    }
} elseif (strlen($cleansearch) > 6 && "-D"===substr($cleansearch,4,2) ) {
    for($i = 10; $i<100;  $i++ ) {
        $test = "IR".$i;
        if($test===substr($cleansearch,0,4) ){   
            $searchyear= " AND DATE_FORMAT(year,'%y') =$i ";
        }
    }
    $searchid= " LPAD(pk,4,'0') LIKE '".substr($cleansearch,6)."%' ";
}
if(!empty($searchid)){
   $wheresearchterm = " OR (".$searchid . $searchyear.") ";
} else {
   $wheresearchterm = "";
}
$query = "SELECT pk, year FROM myTable WHERE 1 $wheresearchterm;";//The search query
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: You said, "I am not aware of a MySQL wildcard character or method that allows you to ignore parts of the column in a search..." Have you looked at the `REGEXP` operator in MySQL? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: You said "legacy design issue"... How much can you change the database structure? Can you update the table? Create a new table maybe?

Comment: @JonathanM, do you think a combination of the Regex and a split of the PHP would be less complicated than the PHP alone?

Comment: @rlanvin, this is only for a search feature; I don't want to modify the table to include redundant information.  This is really legacy more because of the form name, rather than the database structure (if I could change the form name to something like FM1025, it would be much easier).

Comment: You said  performance is a factor to keep in mind here. `REGEXP` isn't exactly known for having great performance, so keep that in mind too.

Comment: @Sablefoste it's not redundant information, since obviously you need to calculate it again all the time, everytime. It's worth considering storing it and index it, to speed up the search and simplify the code greatly. Call the field "redundant_legacy_form_name" if it makes you feel better :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest making a SQL view to make your life a lot easier.

```
CREATE VIEW DocumentIdView AS
SELECT CONCAT('FM', DATE_FORMAT(year,'%y'), '-A', pk) AS docId, pk FROM table
```

Then in your PHP code, you can just do a

```
SELECT b.* FROM DocumentIdView a LEFT JOIN table b ON a.pk = b.pk WHERE a.docId LIKE 'FM15-A1%'
```

Obviously you could combine the two selects if you would rather not have a SQL view.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT CONCAT('FM', DATE_FORMAT(year,'%y'), '-A', pk) AS docId, pk FROM table) a LEFT JOIN table b ON a.pk = b.pk WHERE a.docId LIKE 'FM15-A1%'
```

If this doesn't perform well, I would recommend storing the document ID as a column in your table for fast lookup. Or if updating the table is not an option, create a [materialized view](http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views) for the query as @rlanvin suggests.

Comment: I'd add that if updating the original table is not an option, it's also possible to make a real table from the view, with small triggers to keep it up-to-date.

Comment: Updated answer to include the suggestion.

Comment: Interesting, I have never played with views before.  However, I can confirm the query works.  Good suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Using the MySQL String-Operator `LIKE`, which allows the `%` wildcard, you can split up your string and refine your search criterias.

```
$sql_where = "";
$search = "FM15-A1025";

if (strlen($search) >= 3) {
    $y = int(substr($search, 2, 2));
    $sql_where .= "DATE_FORMAT(year,'%y') LIKE '$y%'";
}
if (strlen($search) >= 7) {
    $pk = int(substr($search, 6));
    $sql_where .= " AND CAST(pk as char) LIKE '$pk%'";
}
```

Note that LIKE has bad performance though, and glueing your SQL-Strings together can be dangerous if you don't pay extra attention avoiding SQL-injections